# is_numeric function not validating plus(+) symbol

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to validate Item No.s from user input. If the plus symbol is placed at the first place then the is_numeric function does not gives error but on placing the + symbol anywhere else it gives the error.

**Case 1 :**

```
$ItemNumber = '+123456789';

if(!is_numeric($ItemNumber))
{
   echo 'Sorry! Invalid Item No. given.';
}
else
{
  echo 'Success';
}

 //Output : Success
```

**Case 2 :**

```
$ItemNumber = '123456789+';

if(!is_numeric($ItemNumber))
{
   echo 'Sorry! Invalid Item No. given.';
}
else
{
  echo 'Success';
}


//Output : Sorry! Invalid Item No. given.
```

Comment: working as intended. I dont think item No. will have sign anyways..

Comment: Simple fix would be to strip plus signs off the end of the string. ````$ItemNumber = rtrim($ItemNumber,'+');````

Comment: @NextLocal but then this will defeat the purpose of validation....

Answer (score 2):

`'+123456789'` is valid numeric string.Check the manual [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), but `'123456789+'` is not

Answer (score 0):

Use [ctype_digit](http://php.net/ctype_digit) php function to get a valid number

```
$ItemNumber = '+123456789';
echo ctype_digit($ItemNumber);//false

$ItemNumber = '123456789+';
echo ctype_digit($ItemNumber);//false

$ItemNumber = '123456789';
echo ctype_digit($ItemNumber);//true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
  $value = "+12345655539997";
  (or)
  $value = "+12345655539997+";
   (or)
   $value = "12345655539997+";

 if(!preg_match('/^[0-9+]+$/', $value) ) {
 echo 'Please enter a valid number';
 }else{
 echo "valid";
 }
```

Demo:https://eval.in/470901

Answer (score 0):

```
$ItemNumber = '+123456789';
if(is_numeric($ItemNumber)){
   echo 'Numeric string value.';
}else{
  echo 'fail';
}
```

that gives `Numeric string value` because `+123456789` valid numeric string but `123456789+` is not.
And `is_numeric` returns `TRUE` if `var` is a number or a numeric string,otherwise it returns `FALSE`.